# Synchronisation Wrappers in java

Tags: java, wrapper

I want to bypass a open  jpa interceptor call and store data in a database( currently it only save in one data base i need to save in a another database synchronizingly ) . to do that i need Synchronisation Wrappers.please help me to understand what  are theese

public static  Collection synchronizedCollection(Collection c);

public static  Set synchronizedSet(Set s);

public static  List synchronizedList(List list);

public static  Map synchronizedMap(Map m);

public static  SortedSet synchronizedSortedSet(SortedSet s);

public static  SortedMap synchronizedSortedMap(SortedMap m);

Comment: You should check their documentation.

Comment: I red it but I couldn't understand

Comment: By default, collections are not thread safe so you have these methods that provide synchronized (thread-safe) collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these methods will internally wrap whatever the collection passed in as the parameter using a Class which implements that Respectable collection interface and Java Monitor Pattern.

Java Monitor Pattern is making use of the Object level monitor (lock) to synchronize all the methods which are exposed through the collection's interface.

This way even if the Collection passed in as parameter is not thread safe. It will be wrapped inside of an object which is thread safe and in turn making the collection thread safe.